# Change colour of circle following mouse on a white background

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, effect

I remade the circle that follows the mouse on https://hello.cuberto.com/
the problem is, when the circle is over a white background, it doesn't change its colour. Does somebody have an idea how I can detect the colour underneath the circle and then change the colour of the circle?

I tried mix-blend-mode: difference, but the problem with that is that the colour of the circle would change to blue if it's on a yellow background.